# WSO2IS 5.3.0 - Issue with email template

Tags: wso2-identity-server

In WSO2IS 5.3.0, I'm changing the email template from the administration console.

But when I received the mail, by calling the soap webservice `UserInformationRecoveryServiceStub.registerUser`, I'm getting the original previous template.
Same thing appends for account confirmation and reset password.
I tried to restart wso2is, same issue, the modifications are well set in the admin gui, but not in the sending email.
Is there a cache or registry to previously clear/delete ?

Although, the email I'm receving still have {} like exemple :

> ```
>         Hi {{user.claim.givenname}},
>
>         You have created an account with following user name
>
>         User Name: {gribo@xxx.com}
>
>         Please click the following link to unlock. If clicking the link doesn't seem to work, you can copy and paste
>         the
>         link into your browser's address window.
>
>         https://localhost:9443/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmregistration.do?confirmation={a38a5b98-e781-4c83-863c-fa7f5c391d98}&userstoredomain={PRIMARY}&username={gribo%40xxx.com}&tenantdomain={carbon.super}&callback={{callback}}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the SOAP based service (which is now deprecated by the new [REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#mePost)) you need to enable the old email template editor to edit the templates for SOAP.

To do that open the `carbon.xml` file, and delete/comment the following line

`<HideMenuItemId>identity_mgt_emailtemplate_menu</HideMenuItemId>`

After updating this config and restarting the server, go to "Configure -> Email Templates" in the admin console and do the required change there. Now it should get updated.

Note that the email template config at the "Main -> Manage" will still be present and will only change the templates for new API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the information should be more explicitely describe in the migration guide and in the email template documentation as well.
In the rest api doc I don't see any parameter for tenan in the register method, is it tenant wise ?