# WSO2 IS 5.3.0 Impossible to unlock account

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I used the soap service to register User, but because of the [email template problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982332/wso2is-5-3-0-issue-with-email-template/41986512), I'm changing to use the [new rest-api](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/apidocs/self-registration/index.html#configuring-rest-api)

I followed [this article](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/User+Account+Locking+and+Account+Disabling) with new method, but I received an error when I called 
`UserIdentityManagementAdminService.unlockAccount`
described in the paragraph :
**Unlocking a user account using the admin service**

The error is :

> {org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.services.UserIdentityManagementAdminService}
>   -  Error occurred while unlocking account for: test@test.com org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Cannot unlock
>   account, IdentityMgtEventListener is not enabled.

But in the new method paragraph it says to disable the IdentityMgtEventListener, and if I enable it, the unlock does not work neither, no error is issue but the account is still locked.

I will use the RemoteUserStoreManagerClient.setUserClaimValues to unlock but I think something is missing in the doc to programatically unlock user after creation...

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have to use RemoteUserStoreManagerClient.setUserClaimValues method. That is the only way to lock unlock user, if you use new-rest-based api for account locking.

Thanks
Isura.